# Virtual directories not showing up in VS 2005

Tags: iis, visual-studio-2005, virtual-directory

How come when I create an IIS based website, any virtual directories created under the main app show up in VS2005 but if I create a file-system based website, then use IIS to configure a virtual directory and use it to run the app, the sub-virtual directories do not show up in VS2005 ?

Thanks in advance.

-SK

Answer (score 0):

Because, as the name says, a file-system based website looks just at the file-system and has therefore no information about any virtual directories created in IIS.

If you want to achieve something similar, then you could "simulate" the virtual directories by creating links/junctions in the file-system (to include another directory at the location where you create the virtual directory for the IIS-based website). This can be done with the tool [Junction](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768.aspx) for example.